# Magento 2 - mouseup/mousedown event not fire on fotorama

Tags: magento2, gallery, fotorama

In Magento 2, mouseup / mousedown event not fire on fotorama gallery.

Does have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jquery? Hope this helps.

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: I use addEventListener.

Comment: It is not working in `fotorama__stage` class. If I placed image outside this class then both event are working properly.